# Adding text onto an svg canvas

Tags: html, typescript, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I'm having issues on adding text onto an svg canvas as it doesn't seem like the text is appearing in the canvas after many attempts.

[image]

I'm working on adding the number 0 on both left and right segment at the upper segment of the canvas but it doesn't seem to appear.

```
function createCounter() {
    let scoreLeft: number = 0;
    let scoreRight: number = 0;

    const svg = document.getElementById("canvas")!,
        counter = new Elem(svg, 'text')
            .attr('text',scoreLeft)
            .attr('x',250).attr('y', 400)
            .attr('font', 'Arial')
            .attr('font-size',32)
            .attr('fill','#FFFFFF')
}
```

The function Elem is basically creating a new svg element, such as shapes and so on but I'm having issue with the text element as it doesn't seemed to appear. Am i missing out on any svg text attributes that causes it to not appear?

Comment: What's the `!` right after `document.getElementById("canvas")` supposed to do? That's a syntax error which causes the next line to not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how to do text into svg

```
<svg height="30" width="200">
<text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```